# Is it safe to push a git repository with SSH to a server instance?

Tags: ssh, git, hosting, fingerprint

My goal is to push a Git repository with SSH onto a server instance on a new hosting service.

I am following the documentation of the new hosting service, and one of the steps is:

```
git remote add xyz $ssh+git://{instance_id}@git.{datacenter_id}.xyz.net/default.git
```

But, I am afraid to run this, it requires me to connect my local computer with this server. This is the first time I am using `git push` and SSH.

My question is, that is this line correct and safe to run?

There is also a Git endpoint fingerprint in the documentation, am I supposed to do anything with that?

Comment: Do you expect it to be significantly different than e.g. your computer connecting to an HTTP or FTP server?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're concerned about?  Any remote you add, regardless of protocol, is going to require you to connect your local computer with the remote server.

Comment: This is fine. This is the way the majority of people out there connect to their SSH repository. Also, “There is also a Git endpoint fingerprint…” you mean the fingerprint check when you connect to the remote server? That is just the check to confirm you want to connect to that sever. Once you okay that, the fingerprint gets set in `.ssh/known_hosts` on your side (the client side). All you describe sounds 100% normal.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks a lot for the detailed comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is safe to run, provided you have enough trust in the new host to put your code in it.

The SSH connection will be used by your local git executable, so its not like the server can do weird things to you by connecting to it. I suppose that they could use a custom SSH or GIT server that implements an exploit for some vulnerability in either git or ssh_client on connected systems, but neither is very likely.

if you trust the remote enough to put your code on it, you should trust it enough to connect to it via SSH+git.

the fingerprint is likely the fingerprint of the SSH host key, so that you can verify that the server you think you are connecting to is actually the server you are connected to, and tell if that ever changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I appreciate it!